# Error displaying unix (time stamp) before 1970 (Drupal 7)

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I am having a problem. In my drupal instance I am having trouble displaying dates before 1970.

I am currently using the type: Date (unix timestamp).

[image]

The interesting thing is that the date is correctly stored in the database.

[image]

However dates before 1970 cannot be displayed (It is empty).

[image]

Comment: are there any errors in the log ? check at /admin/reports/dblog

Comment: you might also check the field display settings (at Structure > Content Types > Manage > Display or /admin/structure/types/manage/content_type_machine_name/display) and your date formats (at Configuration > Regional and langauge > Date and time formats or /admin/config/regional/date-time)

Answer (score 0):

Unix time stamp starts counting at Jan 01 1970 (UTC)
Time before this date is negative.

Comment: Yes I, know... but that should not be a problem, those negative dates are representations of dates prior to Jan 01 1970 (UTC). 
Negative dates should be visible without any problem. I just have no idea why my instance (Drupal 7) can't interpret them.

Comment: I never worked with Drupal. But could it be Drupal ecpects an unsigned integer number of seconds between 0 and 2^31-1 and ignores the sign (MSB)?

Comment: Are you uing strtotime? I just saw a remark at https://www.drupal.org/node/1455576 saying strtotime doesn't workk with dates prior to 1970.

Comment: There's a problem with Drupal 9. You need a patch.